# Making sure the browser will download a file and not open it

Tags: javascript, html, web, amazon-s3

I have an mp3 files on my site and I wish that when a user click on them they will get downloadeded.

Current behiavor is that the file is getting opened by the broweser mp3 player.
I assume its relates to the mime-type but dont know what I should do to fix it.

My mp3 files are located on S3 so  can not change the response header.

Comment: Is there a chance to use a server side script in PHP or something similar?

Comment: One option is to use `<a href="song.mp3" download="song.mp3">Download</a>`, but has limited support now: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Thank Mr Lister !! your solution was right on :) make at an answer and I'll vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to have the mp3 files be attachments by giving them a content-disposition http header.

[This site](http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2009/06/how-to-set-custom-http-headers-for.html) explains how to give custom http headers to files on an AWS system.